# Class initialization list with struct pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am looking at an example of the PIMPL idiom, and I found a line of code I really don't understand. Since I'm new to c++, and OOP, I was hoping somebody could explain what this function does.

**Can somebody clarify this function?**

```
PublicClass::PublicClass(const PublicClass& other)
    : d_ptr(new CheshireCat(*other.d_ptr)) { // <------- This line 
    // do nothing
}
```

/

Here is the example.

```
//header file:
class PublicClass {
public:
    PublicClass();                              // Constructor
    PublicClass(const PublicClass&);            // Copy constructor
    PublicClass(PublicClass&&);                 // Move constructor
    PublicClass& operator=(const PublicClass&); // Copy assignment operator
    ~PublicClass();                             // Destructor
    // Other operations...

private:
    struct CheshireCat;                         // Not defined here
    unique_ptr<CheshireCat> d_ptr;              // opaque pointer
};
```

/

```
//CPP file:
#include "PublicClass.h"

struct PublicClass::CheshireCat {
    int a;
    int b;
};

PublicClass::PublicClass()
    : d_ptr(new CheshireCat()) {
    // do nothing
}

PublicClass::PublicClass(const PublicClass& other)
    : d_ptr(new CheshireCat(*other.d_ptr)) {
    // do nothing
}

PublicClass::PublicClass(PublicClass&& other) 
{
    d_ptr = std::move(other.d_ptr);
}

PublicClass& PublicClass::operator=(const PublicClass &other) {
    *d_ptr = *other.d_ptr;
    return *this;
}

PublicClass::~PublicClass() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ by default provides a copy constructor when the user does not define one: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

The line:

```
d_ptr(new CheshireCat(*other.d_ptr))
```

is simply dereferencing a pointer to an existing `CheshireCat` object and copying it to instantiate a new `CheshireCat` object that the `d_ptr` to the instantiated object points to.

Comment: Technically incorrect. C++ does not provide *trivial* copy constructors, it provides *default* ones.

Comment: Read the link referenced, under section Trivial Copy Constructors:  "The copy constructor for class T is trivial if all of the following is true:
it is not user-provided (that is, it is implicitly-defined or defaulted), and if it is defaulted, its signature is the same as implicitly-defined;
T has no virtual member functions;
T has no virtual base classes;
the copy constructor selected for every direct base of T is trivial;
the copy constructor selected for every non-static class type (or array of class type) member of T is trivial;"

Comment: Your own link contradicts you. `the copy constructor selected for every non-static class type (or array of class type) member of T is trivial`. Nothing here suggests that `CheshireCat` constructor is trivial. Again, correct definition is "...provides **default** copy constructors...". Sometimes those default constructors are trivial, sometimes they are not, it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Structs do not "take values". *Functions* takes values. Constructors are functions. In `new CheshireCat(*other.d_ptr)`, you invoke the **compiler-generated copy constructor** of `CheshireCat`.

You also do **not pass a pointer** but a reference, because you dereference `other.d_ptr` via the overloaded `operator*` of `std::unique_ptr`. In fact, if you wrote `new CheshireCat(other.d_ptr)` or `new CheshireCat(other.d_ptr.get())`, then you would get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `*other.d_ptr` is parsed as equivalent to `*(other.d_ptr)`.  Let's take the syntax `d_ptr(new CheshireCat(*other.d_ptr))` and work from the inside out to determine what it's doing:

- `other` -- a `PublicClass const &` as declared.
- `other.d_ptr` -- a `unique_ptr<CheshireCat> const &`, a reference to the `d_ptr` instance member of `other`.
- `*other.d_ptr` -- the invocation of `operator*` on the `unique_ptr` object, which will yield a result of type `CheshireCat const &` (a reference to the object that the `unique_ptr` object owns).
- `new CheshireCat(*other.d_ptr)` -- takes this `CheshireCat const &` and heap-allocates a new `CheshireCat` object by invoking the copy constructor of the `CheshireCat` type.  This expression is of type `CheshireCat *`.
- `d_ptr(new CheshireCat(*other.d_ptr))` -- constructs the `d_ptr` member of the `PublicClass` object being constructed, using the `CheshireCat *` value.  (This is the [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) of this particular `PublicClass` constructor.)

In other words, all this line is doing is copying the `CheshireCat` object owned by the `other` instance, and giving ownership of that copy to the `PublicClass` object that is being constructed.